# Why is CNN convolution output size in PyTorch DQN tutorial computed with `kernel_size -1`?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, dqn

Based on my understanding, CNN output size for 1D is

`output_size = (input_size - kernel_size + 2*padding)//stride + 1`

Refer to [PyTorch DQN Tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/reinforcement_q_learning.html). In the tutorial, it uses 0 padding, which is fine. However, it computes the output size as follows:

```
        def conv2d_size_out(size, kernel_size = 5, stride = 2):
            return (size - (kernel_size - 1) - 1) // stride  + 1
```

It the above a mistake or is there something I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not a mistake because

```
size - (kernel_size - 1) - 1 = size - kernel_size + 2 * 0
```

with 0 as padding
(it's not code, its an equation sorry for the formatting)
I think the tutorial is using the formula for the output size from the official document which is

```
output_size = ((input_size + 2 * padding - dialation * (kernel_size - 1) - 1) // stride + 1
```

[official doc for conv1d](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html)

Comment: Thanks. Learnt something new - Dilation. Good visuals to explain dilated convolutions at https://github.com/vdumoulin/conv_arithmetic/blob/master/README.md